# Create new resources on muti-accounts on AWS?

Tags: terraform

I am building a small tool using Terraform to generate sandbox on AWS. I will be the owner of every new sandbox and each user will be added as an IAM user with appropriate rights.

The input file looks like this: **users.auto.tfvars**

```
sandboxs_manager = "pierre-alexandre.mousset"

dev_team_members = [
  { name = "brian.davids", is_enabled = true }, { name = "tom.hanks", is_enabled = true }]
```

Which is going to create 2 different AWS accounts:

```
pierre-alexandre.mousset+brian.davids@company.com 
pierre-alexandre.mousset+tom.hanks@company.com
```

What I am now trying to achieve, is to create a simple `S3 bucket` on every new `aws_organizations_account` generated by Terraform.

This is how I am generating AWS accounts on my Terraform:

```
resource "aws_organizations_account" "this" {
  for_each  = local.all_user_names
  name      = "Dev Sandbox ${each.value}"
  email     = "${var.manager}+sbx_${each.value}@company.com"
  role_name = "Administrator"
  parent_id = var.sandbox_organizational_unit_id
}
```

Is there a way to loop over every `id` generated by `aws_organizations_account` to create a `S3 bucket` on each of those newly created account?

Based on [this Github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/19932), I would need to use muti-provider which is not yet supported by Terraform and would probably look like this before to generate my `s3 buckets`:

```
provider "aws" {
  for_each = local.aws_accounts
  alias = each.value.aws_account_id
  assume_role {
    role_arn    = "arn:aws:iam::${aws_organizations_account.this.id}:role/TerraformAccessRole"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: Your proposed code is likely how it would be possible once implemented.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Schuchard , is there currently any other way to loop over of  a list of account IDs to create ressources?

Comment: Probably not as those are tied to credentials, and the credentials are tied to the provider.

Comment: Ok thanks @Matt Schuchard, i need to create a tool to create sandboxs on AWS with a dedicated budget for each sandbox, I will probably have to wait then